# $httpBackend jsonp: No pending requests to flush

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jsonp, httpbackend

On a button click, I make a jsonp call.

```
    function clickHandler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = "some.url.with?params";
            $http.jsonp(url).success(function () {$scope.success();})
                            .error(function () {$scope.failure();});
        }
```

Test:

```
$httpBackend.expectJSONP(this.url + '&' + $.param(this.params)).respond({status: 200});

$('button').click();

$rootScope.$digest(); // this was suggested in few answers, doesn't work for me though

$httpBackend.flush();
```

But I keep getting the **No pending requests to flush failure**.

Is there something different we need to do incase of JSONP calls. Everywhere else, this format works.

PS: yes I make the call(many questions, people actually din make the call or trigger the action that triggered the event). Atleast, I see the code hitting the line where I made the request in the code.

Comment: is clickHandler() in a controller? How is it bound to the button? ng-click?

Comment: Yes it is inside a controller and bound by ng-click

Comment: I think it would be better to get an instance of the controller in your test and then you can call `controller.clickHandler()` instead of `$('button').click()`. If you absolutely must use `$('button').click()` you could try changing `$rootScope.$digest()` to `$rootScope.$apply` but I don't think that will help.

Comment: You won't believe I tried both. And it din work. I tried to directly access the method from the directive's scope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not working because it doesn't look like you've created the `button` DOM element in your test. You'd make your life easier if you just call the function on your `$scope` object which you can easily access in your tests since you've already created it. Try this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ku174UYoNNKiKrIG6pra?p=preview)

**controller**

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.success = function(){
    console.log('success');
  };

  $scope.failure = function(){
    console.log('failure');
  };

  $scope.clickHandler = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = "some.url.with?params";
      $http
        .jsonp(url)
        .success($scope.success)
        .error($scope.failure);
  }

});
```

**spec**

```
describe('Testing a controller', function() {

  var $scope, ctrl, $httpBackend, mockEvent;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_){

    $scope        = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend  = _$httpBackend_;

    mockEvent = { preventDefault: function(){} };

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });

  })); 

  it('should trigger success callback', function() {

    spyOn($scope, 'success');

    $httpBackend.expectJSONP('some.url.with?params').respond({status: 200});

    $scope.clickHandler(mockEvent);

    $scope.$digest();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect($scope.success).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });

});
```

Comment: like I said in the earlier comment, it doesn't work that way either. I noticed an error after debugging through the angular code "Unexpected JSONP". If I use the url to make actual request, it is working fine.That's why I asked "Is there something different we need to do incase of JSONP calls"

Comment: should the response be wrapped inside a method in the faked response too?

Comment: button click wasn't a problem ... just FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

My test was affected by an earlier test in my suite, so few values from the earlier test were getting picked up which were different from what I had asserted. And hence the requests weren't matching. Corrected them. Works now. Sorry for the trouble.